# Nested ExpandableListView's

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I'm starting to implement the following Codebook from an existing application into a mobile version, whose structure is nearly identical to a directory tree:

[image]

---

I've read many posts here are foe about achieving multiple levels in an ExpandableListView, however, all these solutions employ a finite depth. This is fine and everything, as I'm sure I can extrapolate the logic and support N levels (I've implemented a standard (N=2) ELV elsewhere in my app already), however another approach dawned on me.

**Is it possible/recommended/efficient to nest ELV's within each other.** Then, I could maybe logically break the structure up into separate ELV's (2 level), and nest them within each other, instead of trying to have a single ELV support multiple levels/groups ?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got some interesting and disappointing conclusions to post eventually that were drawn during a through investigation into this data structure. In short, it comes extremely close, like one or two  method overrides away from directly supporting nesting. However, bc  those methods are private, as well as the all important ExpandableListConnector member, there's no way to build in support through subclassing. A re-implementation would be necessary, which I find quite unfortunate (unless I'm missing something here).